# In C#, what is the fastest way to remove blank entries in a string[] or List<string>?

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

I have very large string lists and arrays and i found 2 issues that i want to resolve:

1. Remove all entries that are blank strings
2. Remove all entries that are just whitespace

These can be 2 different solution . . not sure if there is a faster way compared to a basic loop or this:

```
array = array.Where(r=>!String.IsNullOrEmpty(r.Trim());
```

Comment: just 2? test both and see

Comment: in .NET 4 you have the method: string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace() which saves you the trim.

Comment: better to do `array.Where(!String.INullOrWhiteSpace())`

Comment: @Jodrell: Too many parentheses.  You don't want to call the method, you want the method group converted to a delegate.  Plus, you can't use `!` like that.  You'd need a lambda expression.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For a `List<T>` there's a *potentially*-faster equivalent, which performs the removal in-place, [`RemoveAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a.aspx):

```
// We can do better than this - see below...
list.RemoveAll(r => String.IsNullOrEmpty(r.Trim()));
```

This *may* be faster in terms of how the repositioning within the list is performed.

It also depends on whether you *want* in-place removal, of course. Personally I'd normally prefer the LINQ approach as it's more flexible and more idiomatic these days - I usually *treat* collections as immutable sequences, even if they're not really :)

One point to note: you don't need to trim a string to find out whether or not it's got any whitespace. You can use [`string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace.aspx), which should really be called `IsNullOrEmptyOrWhitespace` - basically "does it not have content".

This could easily make a *very significant* difference to performance - if you have a lot of long strings, there's no point in having an O(N) operation (`Trim`) just to determine that there's some content... and there's no point creating a new string when you're just going to throw it away again.

**Note: sizes changed from earlier version to give good differentiation between final three cases...**

Here's an example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;

public class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        List<string> list = new List<string>();
        string longString = new string('x', 1000) + " ";
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
        {
            list.Add(i % 100 == 0 ? "" : longString);
        }

        Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        list.Where(r=> !string.IsNullOrEmpty(r.Trim())).ToList();
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("IsNullOrEmpty(Trim): {0}", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        GC.Collect();

        sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        list.Where(r=> !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(r)).ToList();
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("IsNullOrWhitespace: {0}", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        GC.Collect();

        sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        List<string> listResult = new List<string>();
        int countList = list.Count;
        for (int i = 0; i < countList; i++)
        {
            string item = list[i];
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item))
            {
                listResult.Add(item);
            }
        }
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("New list: {0}", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        GC.Collect();

        // This has to be last, as it modifies in-place 
        sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        list.RemoveAll(r => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(r));
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("List.RemoveAll: {0}", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }        
}
```

Sample results on my laptop:

```
IsNullOrEmpty(Trim): 3573
IsNullOrWhitespace: 452
New list: 232
List.RemoveAll: 153
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on the "_may_ be faster" ?

Comment: @Magnus: I haven't tested it, but `List<T>` has more information here (the total size, for example) - it may be able to optimize to reduce the amount of copying required, etc.

Comment: @JonSkeet how is `Trim` O(N)?  It doesn't need to iterate the string to find the end point, after all.

Comment: Could you please add a stopwatch using the classic for(which I bet will be faster?)

Comment: @MassimilianoPeluso: Using the classic for to do *what*, exactly. Please propose some complete code.

Comment: @JonSkee I have "extended" your code to check the performance using also a classic for and a PLINQ solution.I have posted the code thanks anyway.

Comment: @MassimilianoPeluso: Yes, it's a bit faster... but the *big* difference in speed is due to using `IsNullOrWhiteSpace`, and I would then measure to see whether your more complex solution is actually required, or whether the one-liner LINQ solution is good enough.

Comment: @MassimilianoPeluso: And actually, RemoveAll is faster still - will edit that in...

Comment: @JonSkee thanks for your comment. I think the classic for is always faster then LINQ(which uses for behind the scene) the matter is to understand when is better sacrifice performance for readability.

Comment: @JonSkee thanks for editing your code.As I was saying the for is much faster then the LINQ solution. The RemoveAll solution is not using LINQ as RemoveAll is a list member(I was comparing LINQ and for)

Answer (score 5):

A classic `for/foreach` is always faster then any `Linq` to object expression as `Linq` uses `for/ForEach` behind the scene.

Comment: *Always Faster* - Depending on his constraints PLINQ might be faster. But this question is rather open ended :S

Comment: Where exactly LINQ uses `ForEach`?

Comment: what about parallel for?
Anyway a layer of abstraction uses (even if something is not calculable) a bit of resources more. Linq can't be quicker then something on which it is based on.

Comment: @MassimilianoPeluso the point is that PLINQ is not strictly based on foreach.  Therefore it can be faster (though admittedly processor caching and contention means that the array would have to be huge to see a difference- see my note on micro-optimization).

Comment: In general the code is as much faster as is it close to the machine language. You can create a layer of abstraction to make you code more easy to use/read but talking from a medium  high point of view behind the scene you will always have 
if..then..else/While/For and a couple of more language structure. Anything based on them - any layer of abstraction - can't be quicker then them
I know guys Linq is cool but what is cool is not always the best (performance wise)Then we should tuning the performance against the readability to understand when is better to use Linq then more low level structure

Comment: This isn't a matter of closer to the machine language or not.  ForEach (and LINQ `Where()`) is single threaded.  PLINQ (as in *Parallel* LINQ) is multithreaded.  Therefore, when a task can be efficiently parallelized, PLINQ *may* be faster than regular LINQ or ForEach.

Comment: probably the parallel for each would be still faster then the plinq I'll write a test and I'll let you know

Comment: I have posted as expected the classic for is faster the LINQ

Answer (score 5):

The only thing that comes to mind is to use the IsNullOrWhitespace method instead.

```
array = array.Where(r=>!String.IsNullOrWhitespace(r));
```

I doubt you'll notice any speed difference though.  This is an extreme example of micro-optimization.

Comment: +1 - you have to measure your cleanest solution to decide if you would rather opt for a less-clean, but more optimal solution as you need to agree that the compromise in your code is worth the performance gain.

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
array = array.Where(r=>!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(r));
```

If you have a `List<string>`:

```
list.RemoveAll(str => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str));
```

Answer (score 1):

as expected the classic `for` is faster then any LINQ solution

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {


        List<string> list = new List<string>();
        string longString = new string('x', 10000) + " ";
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
        {
            list.Add(i % 100 == 0 ? "" : longString);
        }

        Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        list.Where(r => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(r.Trim())).ToList();
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("IsNullOrEmpty(Trim): {0}", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        GC.Collect();

        sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        list.Where(r => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(r)).ToList();
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("IsNullOrWhitespace: {0}", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);


        GC.Collect();


        sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        //this is result list
        List<string> listResult = new List<string>();
        int countList = list.Count;
        for (int i = 0; i < countList; i++)
        {
            string item = list[i];
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item))
            {
                listResult.Add(item);
            }
        }
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Classic for + IsNullOrWhitespace: {0}", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        GC.Collect();

        sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        list.AsParallel().Where(r => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(r)).ToList();
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("PLINQ IsNullOrWhitespace: {0}", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        Console.Read();
    }
```

on my machine (i5)

```
IsNullOrEmpty(Trim): 6165
IsNullOrWhitespace: 39
Classic for + IsNullOrWhitespace 21
PLINQ IsNullOrWhitespace: 65
```

Comment: You haven't tried List.RemoveAll... (Not that that's LINQ, but it's not a classic for loop, either.)

Comment: as you said RemoveAll is not LINQ